# Conflicting Web Server

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, webserver, web-development

Sorry I literally could not think of a better subject.
Looks like my router is not doing port forwarding for http and https even though my settings say they are on the correct port.

The only thing I changed yesterday was the ssh port to 7689​.  ​This is the history of the commands I ran to open port 7689 for ssh.  Not sure if this relates but was all that changed.
line 700 was an error by me.  Will that affect anything?

`699  vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

700  iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 87689 --syn -j ACCEPT

701  vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config  702  iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 7689 --syn -j ACCEPT

703  service iptables save

704  systemctl iptables save

705  firewall-cmd --add-port 7689/tcp --permanent

706  firewall-cmd --add-port 7689/tcp

707  systemctl enable firewalld

708  systemctl start firewalld

709  systemctl status firewalld

710  firewall-cmd --add-port 2124/tcp --permanent

711  firewall-cmd --add-port 7689/tcp --permanent

712  firewall-cmd --add-port 7689/tcp

713  service sshd restart

714  service sshd status`

But right now, orcacomputers.com won't load.  orcaaccounting.com loads but the page links don't.  hopetonmedia.com shows up with hello world so I'm sitting here scratching my head wondering how to troubleshoot this.

orcacomptuers.com pings from the proper ip.
OS = CentOS7

Answer (score 0):

Looks like  `systemctl enable firewalld`
 turned on my os firewall.  So the solution was:

I turned it off and now the connection go through.

To turn off

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

To disable so it doesn't start on reboot I did

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```